# Handlebars custom if helper else is undefined

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a custom helper, as follows:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('hasAccess', function(val, fnTrue, fnFalse) { 
    return val > 5 ? fnTrue() : fnFalse();
});
```

and my template, as follows:

```
{{#hasAccess this.access}}
    You have access!
{{else}}
    You do not have access
{{/hasAccess}}
```

It works, except fnFalse is undefined. So, how am I supposed to render the 'else' branch?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Handlebars provides custom helpers an object containing the different functions to apply, `options.fn` and `options.inverse`. See https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#conditionals

Your helper could be written as

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('hasAccess', function(val, options) {
    var fnTrue = options.fn, 
        fnFalse = options.inverse;

    return val > 5 ? fnTrue(this) : fnFalse(this);
});
```

And a demo

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('hasAccess', function(val, options) { 
    var fnTrue = options.fn, 
        fnFalse = options.inverse;
        
    return val > 5 ? fnTrue() : fnFalse();
});

var template = Handlebars.compile($('#tpl').html() );
$("body").append( "<h1>access : 1</h1>" );
$("body").append( template({access:1}) );

$("body").append( "<h1>access : 6</h1>" );
$("body").append( template({access:6}) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/template' id='tpl'>
{{#hasAccess this.access}}
    You have access!
{{else}}
    You do not have access
{{/hasAccess}}
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks. I was following this http://thinkvitamin.com/code/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers. It must be out of date. Thanks again.

Comment: I am using Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper(), but getting below error:

Uncaught TypeError: options.inverse is not a function

Comment: Thank you so much for the example there, made it a ton easier to understand.