# ember js action on if statement passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I just need to pass a parameter to an ember action of a specific route.

```
{{#if isSelected 'filters' filter.id}}class="active"{{/if}}
```

my action route definition in the app.js file looks like this

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: (...),
  actions : {
    (...),
    'isSelected' : function(table,obj) {
      return this.store.find(table,obj).get('selected');
    }
  }
});
```

but I got `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must pass exactly one argument to the if helper`

I don't want to write a helper for this because the code would be better organized...

how to do this?

Comment: Tried [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327617/handlebars-custom-if-helper-else-is-undefined)?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is: I can't. passing one argument to the if statement the console shows

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must pass exactly one argument to the if helper
```

it would be a nice feature to have, thought

**EDIT**
I have arranged my needs with this lines of code.

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions : { 
    selectItem : function(table,item){

      this.store.find(table,item.id).then(function(obj){
        obj.set('selected',!obj.get('selected'));
      console.log(obj.get('selected'));
        obj.save();
      });
    },
    selectAll : function(table){
      this.store.find(table).then(function(obj){
        obj.forEach(function(obj){
          obj.set('selected',true);
          obj.save();
        });
      });
    }
}
});
```

and my handlebar (a portion of it)

```
{{#each obj in model.objs}}
  <dd {{bind-attr class="obj.selected:active"}}><a {{action "selectItem" 'filter' obj}}>{{obj.name}}</a></dd>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with object:

```
{{#if isSelected {table: 'filters', id: filter.id} }}class="active"{{/if}}
```